# Time difference between two alike methods to get length of iterable

Tags: python, performance

I have come up with something rather odd. The goal is to evaluate the length of an iterable.

```sh
python -m timeit --setup="x = range(1000)" "x=list(x);len(x)"
```

> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 usec per loop

```sh
python -m timeit --setup="x = range(1000)" "len(list(x))"
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.92 usec per loop

Can anyone explain the reason the first method is quicker ?

I tried to look at assembly instructions, but it does not help understanding this behavior.

With: `x=list(x);len(x)`

```
>>> dis.dis(meth1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

With `len(list(x))`:

```
>>> dis.dis(meth2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (it)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: If this question is really 'why is meth2 faster' the title shouldn't be 'fastest way'.  If the question is 'fastest way', @MartesBerkeley's answer is correct, but there's no need to worry about why one is faster. In any case, the question or the title needs editing

Comment: You're right, I modified the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the fact that *setup* is executed only once.

The test

```
--setup="x = range(1000)" "x=list(x);len(x)"
```

converts the *range* into a *list* and stores it back to `x`. Next iteration, it is already a list, so there's nothing more to do.

If you change that to a different variable name, the difference should be gone:

```
--setup="x = range(1000)" "something=list(x);len(something)"
```

In the other test

```
--setup="x = range(1000)" "len(list(x))"
```

`x` remains a *range* and needs to be converted into a *list* 100000 times.

Comment: You're right! Thanks !